# Can an array be initialised with literals of different types in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

As per the Swift document, if the type of an array is inferred from the array literals. Now I am getting confused that if you assign an `Int`,`String` and `Double` values for an array there are no errors being thrown.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Try the same code [here](http://swiftstub.com) on an online Swift compile` or an Xcode with version 6.3.1 or 6.3.2. I have tried the above one on 6.4.

Now can anyone please tell me what will be the type of array?

And how come this array is allowing to initialise it with different data types?

Thank you.

Comment: Although this is possible to achieve, I heavily advise you find a better way to handle your data. There is a reason why Swift is very specific about array types.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can make an array of `Any`:

```
var sample1: [Any] = [12,"Hello"]
```

This is almost always a mistake, though, which is why Swift requires you to explicitly show the type. The vast majority of things you would want to do (except parse JSON in Swift...) can be done without resorting to this kind of data structure.

For some kinds of arrays, you can use `AnyObject` rather than `Any`. This will require all of the elements to be "object-like" which is a little more specific than `Any`, and is more interoperable with ObjC:

```
var sample1: [AnyObject] = [12,"Hello"]
```

This is also almost always a mistake.

The error you're seeing is that Swift needs "more context." Since your objects do not share an obvious parent below `AnyObject`, Swift doesn't know if you really mean that, or if you made a mistake. In most cases, what you want here is an array of some protocol that all of the elements conform to instead.

Comment: So you mean to tell that the array type is inferred only if we assign it with same type of literals? otherwise if it of [Any]. Right?   Then why am i getting the above error

Comment: Because `[Any]` and `[AnyObject]` are almost always a mistake, you are required to explicitly list it.

Comment: But even if you don't specify it explicitly even then the type is inferred right?

Comment: Swift will never infer `Any` or `AnyObject`. They must always be explicit. Other types may be inferred.

Comment: Yes sir i got that point but as per the above post if i try the code in my xcode with 6.4 and on any online compilers then the scenario is different and i'm getting those error(as in image). And also it works fine with xcode 6.3.1

Comment: I didn't think 6.3 would infer `Any`, but I don't have it handy to check; perhaps it did. In any case, 6.4 will never infer `Any`, and that's the error you are receiving. I don't understand the question. As you say, it won't work unless you add the type explicitly as I show above. That's on purpose. "needs more context" means "I can't infer this type."

Comment: yes thank you man i got your point... but does this works fine even with Dictionaries too , right?

Comment: @VinayakGH dictionaries behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you should try to have your arrays of one data type. It minimizes possibilities for making errors.

So that is why you want to explicitly specify the type of the array to contain Any type of objects.

Your example becomes:

`var array: [AnyObject] = [20, 4.0, ""]`

Notice that I'm using `AnyObject` not just `Any`. The difference between the two is that `AnyObject` must be a class whereas `Any` can be just about anything (tuple, struct, ...).

When you make an array of equal types of objects such as:

`var array = [20, 4, 8]`

The compiler will be kind enough to infer the type for you. So the line above is semantically equal to:

`var array: [Int] = [20, 4, 8]`

If you need any additional info feel free to ask.

Comment: So then an array can be initialised with values of any type? then how its type will be inferred? but still i'm confused with Any and AnyObject...

Comment: It will throw an error stating that you need to be more explicit about the type of things in the array. The difference between `Any` and `AnyObject` is explained a bit better here: http://kuczborski.com/2014/07/29/any-vs-anyobject/